# About LFSR based M209 Cipher Machine

Tags: encryption, classical-cipher, lfsr

Can some one please express M209 Cipher Machine in terms of LFSR with Diagram or any simple method?

Comment: There is no LFSR in Hagelin.

Comment: i want it with M209 not Hagelin

Comment: Well, AFAIK, it is also known as M209-Hagelin due to designer. Anyway, the rotors of M209 are not LFSR. I have got a chance to operate this device. If you want to see how it can be breakable, there were articles in Cryptologia...

Answer (score 1):

The M-209 cipher machine cannot be expressed as an LFSR because it is not LFSR-based. It is its own construction, using six adjustable key wheels whose initial positions acted as the key for ciphering. Its operation is vaguely similar to a standard substitution cipher, but the substitution positions would change for each letter, making cryptanalysis more difficult. It had a period length of 101,405,850.

[image: internal]

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-209